# PHP/MySQL - UPDATE Query inserts new record instead updating the record

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I am creating an Swift application and one of the features is that a user can update their user details and will be replicated in a MySQL database via PHP.

However, when executing the query via a HTTP Request, a new record is inserted into the database rather than updating where the user ID corresponds. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

    require 'Config.php';

    $db = mysqli_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USERNAME, $DB_PASSWORD);

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
        $userId = $_POST['UserId'];
        $forename = $_POST['ForeName'];
        $middleName = $_POST['MiddleName'];
        $surname = $_POST['Surname'];
        $emailAddress = $_POST['UserEmailAddress'];
        $gender = $_POST['Gender'];
        $mobileNumber = $_POST['PhoneNumber'];

        $dbconnect = mysqli_select_db($db, $DB_NAME);

        $query = "UPDATE c1723141_algoTrading.tbluser SET UserEmailAddress='$emailAddress',Forename='$forename',Surname='$surname',Gender='$gender',PhoneNumber='$mobileNumber,MiddleName='$middleName' WHERE c1723141_algoTrading.tbluser.UserId='$userId'";

        mysqli_query($db, $query);

        echo $query;
    }

?>
```

Comment: You have a missing quotation mark after the phone number, so I'm surprised it executes the query without a syntax error, however your code doesn't check whether it executed or not. You should use prepared statements for all sorts of reasons, quotes would be one of them - what when your users surname is `O'Hara`?.

Comment: @droopsnoot this is only to prove that the application is able to update records, silly that I missed out a quotation mark but it's still no use unfortunately. Records are still inserted rather than updated

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have primary key column. If not, create one and set to auto_increment .
other you can do is, if your UserId column is integer then set it to primary key. I don't think there is error with query. Please revert if it doesn't work, will find other solution